# highchart heatmap TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The last update from Highcharts Basic v8.1.0 (2020-05-05) breaks my code.

I have different charts (highcharts and highstocks mixed) on one page (plain static HTML website). I include them with:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

I got an error: TypeError: can't convert undefined to object in the heatmap.src.js.
I tested it with the previous version and the includes are working.

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n9ekhmb0/.

How do fix that? Should I change the order of the includes?

Comment: Could you provide your chart options? It could be a simplified version with dummy data, I need it for test/debug because now even the previous version shows errors. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lq5hmde7/ As a temporary workaround you can use the previous version if you don't need to use any new features/fixed bugs

Comment: Oh that's a good idea with the version over the cdn. Thanks.
The includes is not working, doesn't matter if there is a chart or not. As you can see here  https://jsfiddle.net/n9ekhmb0/.

Comment: May I ask you to test your demo once again in the incognito mode? Everything works fine on my side after cleaning the cache - that was probably a 'half-successfull deploy' issue and there were some differences between modules after the last release.

Comment: It's working again! :) Thanks for the tip with the cache